# How can I identify items?

Tags: divine-divinity

As a Survivor in *Divine Divinity*, I was given access to Identify as a passive skill.

The problem I am facing seems to be that I cannot identify any items I've picked up, as it won't let me actually *use* my ability. Do I need some kind of unmentioned item?

**How do I identify my loot?**

<sup>Note: I do know how to identify with the merchant. I do not know how to identify using my passive skill.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you don't need to actually do anything to identify items with your skill, as items will be automatically identified if your skill is high enough.

The equipment section in [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/371215-divine-divinity/faqs/47588) describes the different levels of equipment and what level of skill is needed to identify them.

> Equipment can make or break your character, especially early in the game.
> Equipment has magical strength levels that correspond to non-magical
> (white) to highly magical (gold).  The scale roughly goes like:

```
        White-gray-blue-green-yellow-gold
```

> To identify gray items you need 1 in Identify skill, blue are 2 in
> Identify, green are 3, yellow are 4, and gold are 5.

The idea of having items identified automatically is confirmed on [this FAQ](http://www.gamebanshee.com/divinedivinity/faq.php):

> *Do I need to identify objects?*
>
> Yes, some objects need to be identified. However, if your identify skill level is high enough, they get automatically identified for you.

Comment: Well, that's discouraging. Now I'm thinking I should start over and get a less useless passive.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that having identify is a pretty useful skill to have, but being able to identify things at an barter location does kind of make it a lot less useful to me.